# Scheduled reboot with crontab didn't go ahead. Why might this be?

Tags: linux, cron

**Information**

I have the following crontab for the root user on Debian 10.

```
root@debian:~# crontab -l
# crontab comments curtailed for serverfault
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

30 3 * * * shutdown -r now
```

If I run `uptime` and `who -b` I get the results of the last time I did a manual reboot (yesterday around 6pm).

```
root@debian:~# uptime
 11:03:19 up 16:29,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00
root@debian:~# who -b
         system boot  2020-12-26 18:34
```

I created the crontab around 7pm yesterday, so it was definitely in place prior to the target time.

**Question**

Is there a reason why this may not have worked? Can I debug this in any way?

Comment: The mail suggestion in the post you linked did help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the log to see if the cron job run at the specified time.

On Debian cron is logged in `/var/log/syslog`, see it there is any error reported if the cron job was activated.

If you do `grep cron /var/log/syslog` is there anything logged at the time cron was suppose to do reboot?

Also check if cron service is running, if you do `systemctl status cron.service` does it say the service is active and enabled.
Cron service needs to be running in order for cron jobs to run.

It could also be an issue with cron not being able to find shutdown command, try using `/usr/sbin/shutdown -r now` in cron.

### For Debian 12 and newer

The traditional log files [have been replaced by `systemd-journald` in Debian 12](https://serverfault.com/questions/1148725/where-is-some-os-logs-in-debian-12), so you can't search in `/var/log/syslog` using tools line `grep` any more. This also affects other GNU/Linux Distributions. But you can use `journalctl` instead and also filter the logs directly there:

```
journalctl -u cron
```

Comment: Interestingly I can see the command in `syslog`. The one line of relevance is `Dec 27 03:30:01 debian CRON[22776]: (root) CMD (shutdown -r now)` but weirdly it doesn't seem to report an error. I don't know how this jibes with what I've seen with `uptime` and `who -b`.

Comment: try running mail command as root, do you have any system mail in root user inbox, on some implementaions cron will by default send system mail to user which runs cronjob if there is any error, it could be a path issue try using /usr/sbin/shutdown in cron

Comment: Found it with the mail command. Strangely running `mail` as `root` returned nothing, but running `mail` as my "normal" user showed me the error from the `root` crontab. Anyway, this is it  `/bin/sh: 1: shutdown: not found`. Should I change `shutdown` to `/usr/sbin/shutdown`?

Comment: This changed worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `/sbin/shutdown -r now` instead of `shutdown -r now` fixed my cron on Ubuntu 18.04